# Network driver missing in arch installation

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, proprietary-drivers

I'm trying to install Arch Linux on my Dell XPS 13 9343, Intel Core i7 inside, but I always had some drivers problem during Linux installations. Particularly, I always had to manually install Wireless driver even after Ubuntu installation.

**Then my question:** how can I get and manually install driver during the Arch installation?

Answer (score 0):

At this point I would like to recommend the ArchWiki, where you can find the corresponding information explicitly for your system:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dell_XPS_13_(9343)

Suppose you are talking about the driver for Wi-Fi:

> Most configurations sport the Dell DW1560 802.11ac adapter. This is
> based on the Broadcom BCM4352 chip which requires proprietary driver
> to work. Packages broadcom-wl and broadcom-wl-dkms provide it.

To identify which package fits your needs, please check this resource:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Broadcom_wireless#broadcom-wl

After that you can install the package with (e.g.):

```
pacman -S broadcom-wl
```

You'll find the packages here:

https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/broadcom-wl/
https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/broadcom-wl-dkms/